# How to extract a part of a string using regex, when starting and ending portion of the string is given

Tags: python, regex, fabric

I'm writing a fabric script to change the nodejs version. To do that i need to remove

> node-v0.10.32-linux-x64

and replace it with

> node-v6.9.1-linux-x64

and vice versa.

Below is the line and i need a regular expression to get the bold section of the line

/home/portweb/software/nodejs/**node-v0.10.32-linux-x64**/bin

Below is the code that changes the nodejs version.

```
@task
def changeVersion(appname='nodejs', rootdir='/home/portweb/software',homedir='/home/portweb',tarfile='node-v6.9.1-linux-x64.tar.gz',nodeversion='node-v'):
    """install nodejs"""

    base_dir = rootdir +'/'+appname


    run ('if [ ! -d ' + base_dir + ' ] ; then mkdir -p ' + base_dir + '; fi')

    put('../package/'+tarfile, base_dir + '/', use_sudo=False)

    with cd (base_dir):
        run('tar -zxf '+ tarfile)


    run ('sed -i \'s/regex/'+nodeversion+'/g\' /home/portweb/.bashrc')

    print "****Nodejs Version Changed"
```

nodeversion = **node-v0.10.32-linux-x64** or **node-v6.9.1-linux-x64**;

Comment: Try `sed -i -E \'s/^\/home\/portweb\/software\/nodejs\/([^\/]+)\/bin$/\1/\'  /home/portweb/.bashrc` (maybe `\/` should be turned into `\\/` in your case, please check).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew have you included the nodeversion that replaces the existing one here?

Comment: If you need to replace that value with a new one, try `sed -E -i 's/(\/home\/portweb\/software\/nodejs\/)[^\/]+(\/bin)/\1'+nodeversion+'\2/' /home/portweb/.bashrc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the regex for sed:

```
"sed -i 's,/home/portweb/software/nodejs/\(.*\)/bin,/home/portweb/software/nodejs/'" + nodeversion + "'/bin,g'"
```

Note that you can use separators other than `/` for legibility, so here we used `,`

Answer (score 0):

You can use fabric sed function to replace in **prueba.txt** the chain you want:

```
def sed_node():
    sed('/home/user/test/prueba.txt', 'node-v0.10.32-linux-x64', 'node-v6.9.1-linux-x64')
```

And run:

$ fab sed_node